# Reproduce Row based on column value and filling those new rows with other column values in r

Tags: r, random, row, creation

I have a table 1 that contains numbers. I would like to create rows that the number of rows comes from Total column. Other column values would be created randomly according to table 1 column values. For instance, table 2 column1 value should has 3 "1" value and rest should be "0". Is there anyone can help me with this?

Table 1

```
   Year Age Total   column1 column2 column3
    2017    15  10         3       4      2
```

Desired Table

```
 Year   Age Total   column1 column2 column3
2017    15  1          1       0      0
2017    15  1          0       1      0
2017    15  1          0       0      1
2017    15  1          0       0      1
2017    15  1          1       0      0
2017    15  1          0       1      0
2017    15  1          1       0      0
2017    15  1          0       1      0
2017    15  1          0       1      0
2017    15  1          0       0      0
```

Comment: Why are there 9 rows in the expected output?  Have you tried writing a script yet?

Comment: I missed 1 row. I made edit now.

Comment: I applied following code to create rows, but I can't fill the rows.     
{InsertRow(data = data, NewRow = data[,],  RowNum = data$Total)}

Comment: 1 row should have only 1 1, right? Can there be two 1's in one row since it is random ?

Comment: Hi Ronak Shah, that would be okey for first step. We could improve that if you can share with us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of having three columns with mutually exlusive binary entries, it might be simpler to just convert it froma wide to long format and then expand it:

```
df<-data.frame(year=2017,age=15,col1=3,col2=4,col3=2)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>%
  gather('key','value',col1:col3) %>%
#   year age  key value
# 1 2017  15 col1     3
# 2 2017  15 col2     4
# 3 2017  15 col3     2  
  filter(value>0) %>%  # Avoid keys with 0 values
  group_by(year,age,key) %>%
  expand(value=1:value)%>%
# year   age key    value
# <dbl> <dbl> <chr>  <int>
#   1  2017    15 col1       1
# 2  2017    15 col1       2
# 3  2017    15 col1       3
# 4  2017    15 col2       1
# 5  2017    15 col2       2
# 6  2017    15 col2       3
# 7  2017    15 col2       4
# 8  2017    15 col3       1
# 9  2017    15 col3       2
ungroup()%>%select(-value)
# # A tibble: 9 x 3
# year   age key  
# <dbl> <dbl> <chr>
#   1  2017    15 col1 
# 2  2017    15 col1 
# 3  2017    15 col1 
# 4  2017    15 col2 
# 5  2017    15 col2 
# 6  2017    15 col2 
# 7  2017    15 col2 
# 8  2017    15 col3 
# 9  2017    15 col3
```

Comment: Hi Rhot, thank you for your reply. I have 2 issue. First, in my real data there are some 0 values in column such as col3=0. I applied it but it produced 2 row for col3=0. Second, my data set has 88 column like table 1 with different age. How can I apply this code into 88 columns?

Comment: @AtacanGarip, I've modified the code to avoid the error with 0's. Second, if you have N consecutive columns like col_1, col_2, ... col_N : you can select them using the phrase `col1_:col_N` in the gather satement. If there are no extra columns between column1 and column88, then there should be no problems

Comment: I applied it to my dataset and it worked. Thank you so much for your help